# Django reverse url in javascript

Tags: javascript, django, location, href, reverse

This javascript

```
window.location.href = "{% url 'namespace:name' object.slug " + currentRow + " %}"
```

results in a NoReverseMatch error because it takes "currentRow" as a parameter instead of the value behind currentRow.

Comment: You should understand that you are trying to mix server side and client side scripting there, obviously that doesn't work, use the [forloop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) logic to set and read ids.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing Javascript and the Django template engine.

The Django template engine sees no Javascript variables. No script tags. It only sees text.

Javascript is processed on the clientside, after your HTML and Javascript is generated on the server side by the Django template engine.

If you have a context variable (e.g. coming from your Django view or maybe created in a `{% for %}` loop) named `currentRow`, you can use it directly like so:

```
    window.location.href = "{% url 'namespace:name' object.slug currentRow %}"
```